# Angular 11 can't access object property dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular11

I have to access to a subset of my object properties and store the label and the value in another array.  Basically I have this object:

```js
    myObject: CustomObject {
    prop1: value1,
    prop2: value2
    prop3: value3
    }
```

and as output I need an array with objects of type: `{label: string, value: number}`.
I need to fill this array with prop1 and prop2 and their values, so that I have something like this:

```js
    myArray = [{label: prop1, value: value1}, {label: prop2, value: value2}]
```

What I've tried is this:

```js
    labels = ['prop1', 'prop2'];
    labels.forEach((l: any) => {
      this.myArray.push({ label: l, value: this.myObject[l] })
     })
```

or also this.myObject.l

But I get this error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any'
> can't be used to index type 'MyObject'

I've changed the type of "l" to string but I got:

> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type

What's the correct way to do this?

> myObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `any`, you can use `keyof` to tell typescript that labels is an array of strings where strings are the keys of your interface:

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbAeQCMArCBMZAbwChl7kAHKHRgRgC5k4QBPAbjoNmrAExceAofRGMAzBL6CAvjRoIcIbMjy9iZClwzZ8+8pQC81aUxbsubADQ3Z45KOcNbrBcjnPVdU1tABs4IggQzC4ACgBrCF4cGDQsXEJScwBKAG0AXWQrHIByWTZix2RSu1FivMEgrUpdAEEoKDheQuQwiKiAOjw4RhjeyMKAPmQYqh7wyMqANzgQ9AguXTMKHLGQguUsrMbMHBCIfpCcAHMY1vbOrKA)

```
interface CustomObject {
    prop1: any;
    prop2: any;
    prop3: any;
}

const myObject: CustomObject = {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 2,
    prop3: 3,
}

const labels: (keyof CustomObject)[] = ['prop1', 'prop2'];

const myArray = labels.map(label => ({ label, value: myObject[label] }))
console.log(myArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries` function to iterate over key/value pairs:

```js
const myObject = { prop1: 'value1', prop2: 'value2', prop3: 'value3' }
let myArray = [];

Object.entries(myObject).map((item)=>{ myArray.push({label:item[0], value:item[1]})})
console.log(myArray)
```